# How to created Grid using angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-bootstrap

How to Create the below grid using angular 5 and bootstrap grid. The names will come from an array.

1. Name 1   Name 4  Name 7
2. Name 2   Name 5  Name 8
3. Name 3   Name 6  Name 9

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Comment: Not using tables. But using bootstap grid format.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with `row` and `col` in this way:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4">Name 1</div>
  <div class="col-4">Name 2</div>
  <div class="col-4">Name 3</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4">Name 5</div>
  <div class="col-4">Name 6</div>
  <div class="col-4">Name 7</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4">Name 8</div>
  <div class="col-4">Name 9</div>
  <div class="col-4">Name 0</div>
</div>
```

or you can use `ngFor` in this way

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4" *ngFor="let user of Users">
    {{user.name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to show 3 items per column, you have to change your Array struct to something like :

```
export Class User {
  public name1: string;
  public name2: string;
  public name3: string;
}
```

then your `User[]` will be like this :

```
this.myUserList:User[] = [
  {
    name1 = "Mark",
    name2 = "John",
    name3 = "Matt",
  },
  {
    name1 = "Mark1",
    name2 = "John1",
    name3 = "Matt1",
  },
  {
    name1 = "Mark2",
    name2 = "John2",
    name3 = "Matt2",
  }  
];
```

finally your ngFor will be like this

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4" *ngFor="let user of Users">
        {{user.name1}}{{user.name2}}{{user.name3}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is it possible to do without change in array structure?

Answer (score -1):

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wronyd1c/1/) using hidden and visible classes to achieve the desired result.

[Desktop View](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/90459/embedded/result/)

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">Name 1</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12">Name 2</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12">Name 3</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12">Name 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 hidden-md">
  <div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-12">Name 5</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12">Name 6</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12">Name 7</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12">Name 8</div>
  </div>
</div>
```